# Unity load scene in editor playmode synchronously

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

## Main Question

I'm trying to load a scene in the editor while in playmode and get the exact behaviour of:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(ScenePath, LoadSceneMode.Single);
```

**Except without requiring the scene to be in the build settings**.

I would have expected this to work:

```
EditorSceneManager.LoadSceneInPlayMode(ScenePath, new UnityEngine.SceneManagement.LoadSceneParameters(LoadSceneMode.Single));
```

However the scene appears to load asynchronously, which I don't want for my particular use case.

Is there a way to acomplish what I'm looking for here?

### Additional details (my use case and "why" I want this)

What I'm doing is creating a loader for scene sets that will additively load a bunch of scenes with different constraints on their loading behaviour (such as: load async, always reload when transitioning same->same, and other features). I have this working fine in the editor while I'm not in play mode, I have it working fine in a built player, but the last case is getting this to work while in the editor **and in play mode**.

The reason I need "single" loading at all is when you transition from one scene set to another and they share no common scenes. Since I can't unload every scene, I'm just skipping the unload step all together and having the first synchronously loading scene load with LoadSceneMode.Single to cause everything else to unload.

On the off chance it's relevant (I really hope not) I'm trying to do this from inside a custom editor's OnInspectorGUI call. I'm triggering it from a button press in there.

### Options I'm aware of:

- `EditorSceneManager.OpenScene` with `OpenSceneMode.Single`

  - problem: Does not work in play mode
- `EditorSceneManager.LoadSceneInPlayMode` with `LoadSceneParameters(LoadSceneMode.Single)`

  - problem: Scene is not loaded synchronously
- `SceneManager.LoadScene` with `LoadSceneMode.Single`

  - problem: Scene is required to be in the build settings
- `EditorSceneManager.LoadScene` with `LoadSceneMode.Single`

  - problem: Scene is required to be in the build settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a misunderstanding of what `SceneManager.LoadScene(ScenePath, LoadSceneMode.Single);` would even do.

A friend had pointed out the docs clearly state the load will happen within 1 frame, not actually at the call-site.

If you're facing a similar issue there are a few options. You could load async and subscribe to that callback to perform activation them. Another option is to subscribe to `SceneManager.sceneLoaded` and perform activation there.